# How do I select my city in Drumo?

Tags: profile

I am not sure I understand what is going on with Drumo, I signed up but it seems only two cities are offered:

- Sydney
- Singapore

I am not from any of these cities. I decided to select one just to see if that's how the app operated. Then I was redirected to

> singapore.drumo.com

Okay so I see cities at the top:

[image: Cities in Drumo]

Maybe I can change it there? But all I see there are:

- Australia
- Japan
- China
- Singapore
- Taiwan

How can I add a new city and select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are offering only Sydney (Australia), Singapore and Tokyo (Japan) for now. And they will expand to Melbourne, Adelaide, Brisbane, Perth (Australia), Osaka (Japan), Hong Kong, Shanghai (China), Taipei (Taiwan), or so it seems.

[image]

The company is based in Sydney, Australia, so that's most likely why it started with that part of the world.